# Password field <p:password> Value Won't Re-Appear In Form After Saved And Selecting That Row From Data Table

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

So, I am taking in a password value from a form which is being saved to an object. The objects are saved to a data table. I have the functionality to allow a user to select a row from the data table, and the values for that object will be populated back into the form. Unfortunately, all values will populate except the password field. If I alter the password field to become an inputText, the value will be shown after selecting the row from the data table. Below is the code. Thanks.

HTML
    
    
    
        
            Customer Registration

```
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:commandButton value="Submit" image="ui-icon-check" ajax="false" actionListener="#{createPerson.createPerson()}"/>
            </p:panelGrid><br/>
            <p:panel id="table">
            <p:dataTable id="dataTable" editable="false" var="person" paginator="true" rows="5" selectionMode="single"
                         value="#{createPerson.dataModel}" rowKey="#{person.id}">
        <f:facet name="header">  
            Record 
        </f:facet>  
            <p:ajax listener="#{createPerson.processUserSelection}" event="rowSelect" update=":createPersonForm"/>
            <p:ajax listener="#{createPerson.processUserUnselection}" event="rowUnselect" update=":createPersonForm"/>

            <p:column sortBy="id" headerText="ID">  
            <h:outputText value="#{person.id}" />  
            </p:column>  

            <p:column sortBy="ssn" headerText="SSN">  
            <h:outputText value="#{person.ssn}" />  
            </p:column>  

           </p:dataTable>
        </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Person

```
public class Person {
    private String ssn;
    private String id;

    public String getSsn() {
        return ssn;
    }

    public void setSsn(String ssn) {
        this.ssn = ssn;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Create Person

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.UnselectEvent;

@ManagedBean(name = "createPerson")
@SessionScoped
public class CreatePerson {
    private Person person;
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    private PersonDataModel dataModel;
    private static int id = 0;

    public CreatePerson() {
        person = new Person();
        dataModel = new PersonDataModel(personList);
    }

    public String getSsn() {
        return person.getSsn();
    }

    public void setSsn(String ssn) {
        person.setSsn(ssn);
    }

    public void createPerson(){
        System.out.println(" Submit Button clicked..");
        System.out.println(" SSN: " + person.getSsn());
        if (person.getId() == null || person.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("-1")) {
            //New Person
            person.setId("" + (id++));
            personList.add(person);
            person = new Person(); 
            person.setId("-1");
        }
        else {
        }

    }

    public void processUserSelection(SelectEvent evt) {
        System.out.println(" Row selected from the Data Table .");
        this.person = (Person) evt.getObject();
    }

    public void processUserUnselection(UnselectEvent evt) {
        System.out.println(" Row unselected from the Data Table .");
        this.person = new Person();
        this.person.setId("-1");
    }

    public PersonDataModel getDataModel(){
        return this.dataModel;
    }
}
```

Data Table Class

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;
import org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel;

public class PersonDataModel extends ListDataModel<Person> implements SelectableDataModel<Person>{

    public PersonDataModel() {
    }

    public PersonDataModel(List<Person> data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    public Person getRowData(String rowKey){

        System.out.println("Key = " + rowKey);
        List<Person> persons = (List<Person>) getWrappedData();

        for (Person person : persons) {
            if(person.getId().equals(rowKey)){
                return person;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Valid Person not found");

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(Person person){
        return person.getId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a high risk to display password ,if you will look into Primeface `<p:password />` its a extension of JSF  `<h:inputSecret />` .
It have a attribute called `redisplay` by default its value should be `false`

> Boolean flag indicating whether or not a previously entered password
>   should be rendered in form. Default is false.

Now add this attribute(`redisplay="true"`) in your component.

For more information you can check [Tag inputSecret](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/inputSecret.html)

> Render the clientId of the component as the value of the "name"
>   attribute. Render the current value of the component as the value of
>   the "value" attribute, if and only if the "redisplay" component
>   attribute is the string "true". If the "styleClass" attribute is
>   specified, render its value as the value of the "class" attribute.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much for the information!

Comment: It's great you're good at searching for answers, but it would be more great if you vote for close as duplicate instead of scattering the knowledge base with duplicates without attribution.

Comment: @Subodh - Wasn't familiar with accepting an answer. It has been done.

Comment: @BalusC - Is that directed at me? I'm not familiar with voting for close as duplicate, and I did spend time searching for this answer, apparently not good well enough though.

Comment: No, Subodh just [plagiarized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do) an earlier answer of mine.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC for comment